# Angular to call a post and get call followed by again post and get call once the previous get call is completed

Tags: angular, httpclient

I have post call followed by get call as below:

```
 sendMessage(value) {
  getMessages(value);
 }

  getMessages(value) {
   this.http.post('url').subscribe((response)=> {
      if(response) {
        this.http.get('url').subscribe((getresponse)=> {
          if(getresponse) {
          // get call completed.
          }
        });
      }
    });
  }
```

i need to call post followed by get again after completion of previous get then post followed by get.
currently when the user sends messages continuously may be twice sendMessage() method gets triggered twice but the call is happening like post call, post call then followed by get call get call. instead it should be post call followed get call and then for second message post followed by get call.

can you please let me know how we can achieve this in angular?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you're after, but you can use concatMap operator and execute both subscriptions sequentially in one subscription

```
getMessages(value) {
 const both = this.http.post('url')
  .pipe(
    concatMap(result => {
        // here you have result to use in get
        this.http.get('url')
    })
  )
  .subscribe(result2 => {
    // do some stuff
 });
}
```

Comment: Nope from post i need to get some data that needs to be passed to get request call, i need to get the indication that post and get is completed, then only trigger for the next message post followed by get call